# Copy multiple files using command `xargs`

Tags: bash, xargs

I'd like to  copy the files searched by command `find` to the currernt directory

```
    # find linux books
    find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
  # the result
    ../Books/LinuxCollection/Linux_TLCL-17.10.pdf ../Richard Blum, Christine Bresnahan - Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible, 3rd Edition - 2015.pdf ..
```

Test to copy the files to the current dir using command `cp'

```
 find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 cp .
```

Get error:

```
    usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
           cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

I work out the problem with command substitution

```
    cp $(find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -print0) .
```

How to accomplish it with `xargs`?

Comment: Why do you want to pipe the output of find into xargs? Wouldn't it be easier to use the find option `-exec cp {} . \;`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the `cp` error indicates, the target directory must come last. Since it looks like your `cp` doesn't have an equivalent of GNU `cp`'s `-t` option, you have to get xargs to insert the filename between `cp` and `.`:

```
find ... | xargs -0 -I _ cp _ .
```

where `-I` is used to tell which string is to be replaced with the input (in this case I'm using `_`, though `{}` is also commonly used).

Of course, this can be done with `find` itself:

```
find ~ -type f -iregex '.*linux.*\.pdf' -exec cp {} . \;
```

Comment: Tip: don't use -I _ if your command also contains underscores. It took me way too long to figure that one out.

Comment: The pure find command worked for me, thanks.